# $|\int f \ d\alpha| \leq \int |f| \ d\alpha$ (Rudin 6.13)

Tags: integration, inequality, proof-explanation, riemann-integration

I'm reading Rudin's proof of theorem 6.13,

$$\left|\int_a^b f\ d\alpha \right| \le \int_a^b |f| \ d\alpha$$

and realizing there's a step I can't seem to understand.  We let $c=\pm 1$ such that

$$\left|\int f \right| = c\int f = \int c f \leq \int |f|$$

The last step is justified by $cf\leq |f|$.  But it seems to me that it could be possible that both $c = 1$ and also $f(x) < 0$ for some values of $x$.  I assume we must be saying here that, at every $x\in[a,b]$ we have $cf(x) \leq |f(x)|$, but this doesn't seem true.  I'm sure I'm misinterpretting or misunderstanding something, but can't find what it is.  Because if we're saying that $cf(x)\leq |f(x)|$ holds *for all $x$* then that seems false.  And if we say that it holds *for some $x$* then it seems like we can't infer $\int cf \leq \int |f|$.

My thought about how to approach this problem would have been to break $f$ into regions where it is positive and negative, and integrate on each region.  However, that would assume $f$ is piece-wise continuous, and we'd like a more general result.  So it seems to me that this style of proof would be inadequate.

Answer (score 6):

The number $c$ is either $1$ or $-1$, and therefore $cf(x)$ is either $f(x)$ or $-f(x)$. And both $f(x)$ and $-f(x)$ are smaller than or equal to $|f(x)|$. So, yes, $(\forall x\in[a,b]):cf(x)\leqslant|f(x)|$. And it follows from this that, indeed$$\int_a^bcf(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\int_a^b|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx.$$